# Escaping Angle Brackets in Excel

Tags: excel, escaping

I'm trying to create a table of PGP key names, many of which include angle brackets <> around part of the name.  Excel attempts to creating email hyperlinks out of them, and I don't want it to.  I've tried selecting the cells and removing formatting, but all it does is remove the hyperlink.  If I enter  into a cell and press enter, it deletes the angle brackets from the cell's data, and removing formatting doesn't restore them.  Does anyone know how to force Excel to treat what I enter as literal string and stop trying to help me when I don't want it to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type ' before the data entry in the field, in this case Excel usually treats it as just normal string.

Comment: It does do that, but the backtick is still included in the final cell, is there a way to escape the data and just show the info inside the <>?

Comment: Yup, ' = Single quote. It does the trick, even if you want to add show the formula in the cell, the single quote shows it. Glad it worked out and all the best.